# production.ERROR: Trait "Laravel\Cashier\Billable" not found

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-cashier

I have Laravel Cashier mostly working on my localhost, but I want to test it on my server. I

- updated the .env file for the server
- ran npm run build
- committed and pushed the code to the server

I assumed this would work properly, but I'm getting the following error.

```
production.ERROR: Trait "Laravel\Cashier\Billable" not found
```

I assume that I'm missing some files in my git push, but can't actually see Laravel\Cashier\Billable on my working localhost version, so I'm not sure where to look. I have removed 'vendor' from the excluded files, because I've found they're necessary for some of my add-ons.

What else can I try?

My .env

```
APP_NAME="Language Teaching Games"
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:**************
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://myserver.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=error
```

My app/Models/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles, Billable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function sharedCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SharedCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I have removed 'vendor' from the excluded files_" fyi, the idea is to run `composer install` on your staging/live server, so the packages required for your environment get installed

Comment: My server doesn't have composer and I don't have rights to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and turns out in my case my disk was at 100% so composer install was failing. The actual server error behind this was fwrite(): Write of 2170 bytes failed with errno=28 No space left on device. Adding 100GB and extending the hardisk than composer update did the trick.